# how to find vertex of  parallelotope closest to given point P in R^n ? (Or minimize quadratic form over {+-1}) Is it NP ? 

Tags: algorithms, np, lattices

Consider a  parallelotope in R^n and some point "P" in R^n.
What algorithms (except of brute force) can be suggested to find the closest vertex of paralleloptope to "P" ?

Is it NP ?

Parallelotope has 2^n vertex, not arbitrary 2^n point in R^n are vertex of paralleloptope,
so clever algorithm should somehow use this additional information, while brute force search over 2^n points does not use.

==

Reformulation:

after choosing origin in the center of parallelotope
we can come to the following algebraic version of the problem:
minimize over x_i = {-1,+1} the quadratic form:
\sum a_ij x_i x_j - \sum x_i v_i

Answer (score 3):

This looks almost like the [Max-CUT](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/maxcut-jacm.pdf) problem to me (you have minimize instead of maximize, but you can just flip the signs of the matrix $A$)

In general, you problem is an instance of a binary quadratic program, so it will be hard to solve. Have a look at some solvers [on this webpage](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/qp/qp.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the MIMO detection problem, which is NP hard. Here is a paper with a semidefinite relaxation:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.163.3233&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Then, there exist some easy instances of the problem, if your matrix of the quadtratic form is negative semidefinite and rank deficient. Check these for example

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.594&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://www.telecom.tuc.gr/~karystinos/paper_TIT3.pdf (algorithm included)